# Redux how much data should be in a reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

How big should a reducer state be?

If i had a form that had multiple fields and those all can change with onChange handlers on the respective input fields.

```
  reducerState = {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    phoneNumber: '',
    emailAddress: '',
  }
```

Every change i make in a certain field would have to return a new state. Is this problematic in terms of performance or anything like that? This basically leads to how much data should a reducer store and does it vary depending on how often that state will update?

Comment: For something small like this, the size of your state is not going to matter. I would worry more about the cost of diffing the virtual DOM and rerendering over the size of your state.

Comment: @Wex so to solve that problem would be to add a debounce kind of thing with the input's onChange? Also, would we want to add a key value into a state that changes often because of inputs or separate that into its own reducer? an example would be like an inputValue and searchResults in the same reducer.

Comment: MouseEvents almost certainly need some kind of debouncing. Input changes which trigger rerenders may as well. In practice, a lot of this stuff depends on how you perceive the performance. If you don't need it, don't overcomplicate your application. I like using the [Performance Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference) provided by chrome when I'm trying to evaluate these types of things.